# Passing multiple values to a function call (Python)

Tags: python, function

```
import re
def strip_tags(value):
    "Return the given HTML with all tags stripped."
    return re.sub(r'<[^>]*?>', '', value)
```

I have this function to strip HTML tags, but it seems to accept only single value, what do I need to change if I want to pass multiple (not fixed) values at once?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python offers a way to use arbitrary-length argument lists:

```
def myfunc(*args):
    for argument in args:
        print "myfunc was given", argument
```

If you put `*args` in your function definition, all values passed to the function are available as a tuple called `args`. Note that you can also put additional arguments before `*args`,
like

```
def my_other_func(name, *args):
```

so the first argument will be available as `name`, the rest will be in the tuple `args`.

It is convention, but not neccessary, to call this parameter `args`. As long as there's an asterisk in front of it, you can call it whatever you like.

Comment: There is a good (and very quick) tutorial showing how to use not only * but also ** (dictionaries) for passing arguments, here: http://www.technovelty.org/code/python/asterisk.html

Answer (score 2):

Could you use a loop.

```
for value in values:
    strip_tags(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass in `value` as an array of strings, and then return the array of cleaned values.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
def strip_tags(values):
  return map(lambda i: re.sub(r'<[^>]*?>', '', i), values)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the values are independent of each other, then don't modify strip_tags, just change how you call it:

```
values = [some_value, another_value]
values = [strip_tags(v) for v in values]
# values[0] is now the strip_tags version of the old values[0]
# similar to values[0] = strip_tags(values[0]), except for every item
```

If the values are related, such as being adjacent pieces of the same file, then concatenate them before using strip_tags:

```
values = [some_value, another_value]
result = strip_tags("".join(values))
# note result is single string
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a function written over the function you have provided. this would take in a list of values and return the corresponding processed list:

```
import re
def strip_tags_list(values):
     return map(strip_tags, values)
```

note: this would work on python 2.6 and earleir versions. on python 3.0, you would have to explicitly convert the result of map() to list using list().